# Hibernate - Annotations to apply operation on entity field?

Tags: java, hibernate, hierarchical-data

I have the following JAVA entity

```java
@Table(name = "some_table", schema = "some_schema")
public class SomeEntity{

    @Id
    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 0, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "node", nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String node;

}
```

the `node` property is a `HierarchicalId` type.
When I create a new `SomeEntity` instance, with a `node` value '/1/1/', it works fine.
However, I'd like to annotate the `node` field so that everytime a `SELECT` query  is made, it will select the `node.ToString()` (to get the readable string representation of the `node` property) instead of `SELECT node`.

The `SELECT node` returns X instead of '/1/' and I would like to get '/1/' instead of X.
How can I do that ?
Is that possible to achieve that without using native query ?
Thanks for your help.